# display 3 div in columns, then 1 div, using a loop

Tags: loops, display

I would like to have 3 div in a row, then , when I click on one of them, a div which will take 100% of those 3 rows will be display under it.

**html**

```
<div className={styles.features_type}>
                    {links.map(link => (
                    <div key={link.id} className={openTab === link.id ? styles.feature_open : ""}>
                        <div className={styles.features_cards}>
                            {link.subMenus.map(subMenu => (
                                <div key={subMenu.id}>
                                    <div onClick={() => {openMenu(subMenu.id)}}
                                        className={`${styles.features_card} ${active ? styles.active : ""}}`}>
                                            <h5>{subMenu.title}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    {menuOpen === subMenu.id && (
                                    <div className={styles.features_cardContent}>
                                        {subMenu.subsubMenu.map(sub => (
                                        <div key={sub.id}>
                                            <p>{sub.paragraph}</p>
                                            <ul>
                                                {sub.elements.map((element, index) => (
                                                    <li key={index}>
                                                        <p>{element}</p>
                                                    </li>
                                                ))}
                                            </ul>
                                            <div>
                                                <button>Commander</button>
                                                <a href="#">En savoir plus →</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

**My const**

```
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Titre',
            subMenus: [
                {
                    id: '01',
                    title: 'Titre',
                    subsubMenu: [
                        {
                            id: '01',
                            paragraph: 'paragraph',
                            elements : [
                                'elements.',
                                'elements.',
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: '02',
                    title: 'Titre',
                    subsubMenu: [
                        {
                            id: '01',
                            paragraph: 'paragraph',
                            elements : [
                                'elements.',
                                'elements.',
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: '03',
                    title: 'Titre',
                    subsubMenu: [
                        {
                            id: '01',
                            paragraph: 'paragraph',
                            elements : [
                                'elements.',
                                'elements.',
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: '04',
                    title: 'Titre',
                    subsubMenu: [
                        {
                            id: '01',
                            paragraph: 'paragraph',
                            elements : [
                                'elements.',
                                'elements.',
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },

    ]
```

**Function to open one menu**

```
        if (menuOpen === id) {
            setIsMenuOpen(null)
        } else {
            setIsMenuOpen(id)
        }
    }
```

I tried to move the menu that I want to diplay 100% but it won't show where I want.

[Here's an example of what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA4a1.png)

And what I want
[And what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4dkA.png)

A little help about what I am doing wrong will be very appreciate
I'm lost, do I modify the css , the js, the html ?

Thank you

Still didn't figured out how to do it. The loop make it difficult. I don't know how to manage to have three columns in one row, then 1 colums in one row.
Here's some of my css

```
.features_cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.features_card {
    max-width: 310px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 60px 25px 30px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 50ms;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 100% width container hidden and change property on click action. Add different classes and set width properties to it.
If this is a grid use grid-column-start and grid-column-end css properties.
If you use bootstrap or something similar class col-12 should fill all width of row container.

Comment: Thanks for your help Константин Джанов. I tried to use grid-colums and grid-rows like you said but it doesn't seems to affect anything.